# Getting the Y coordinate for every occurrence of a particular string in a UITextView for line numbering

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I'm trying to get the y positions of every `\n` character in a UITextView so I can align line numberings alongside the UITextView for accurate line numbers. What I'd like to do is get an array of the Y coordinates of every occurrence of `\n`.

At the moment, I can get the CGSize for the current word, but I'm not quite sure how I can adjust this in order to get the Y coordinate of every occurence of a particular word.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
NSRange aRange = self.editorText.selectedRange;
if(range.location<self.editorText.text.length)
{
    NSString * firstHalfString = [self.editorText.text substringToIndex:range.location];

    NSString *temp = @"s";
    CGSize s1 = [temp sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]
                 constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - 40, MAXFLOAT)  // - 40 For cell padding
                     lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; // enter you textview font size

    CGSize s = [firstHalfString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]
                           constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - 40, MAXFLOAT)  // - 40 For cell padding
                               lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; // enter you textview font size


    //Here is the frame of your word in text view.
    NSLog(@"xcoordinate=%f, ycoordinate =%f, width=%f,height=%f",s.width,s.height,s1.width,s1.height);

    CGRect rectforword = CGRectMake(s.width, s.height, s1.width, s1.height);
    // rectforword is rect of yourword


}
else
{
    // Do what ever you want to do

}

return YES;
}
```

The main part I'm not sure about is getting each occurrence of the character in such a way that I can retrieve its coordinates.

Is there a way to do this? Or is there an easier way for me to implement line numbering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is custom parsing your NSString and appending #)  to the start of each line an option?

It's a non-trivial bit of string parsing and manipulating to accomplish, but it has the added benefit of not having to care at all about yCoordinates and other messy layout based parameters.

Comment: That's actually quite a good piece of lateral thinking; any idea how I would then format the line numbers differently from the rest of the text?

Comment: I wasn't really sure where you'd be getting your <code>\n</code> elements from, but I assumed you could count them in your custom parsing. Not gonna lie, facing the drudgery of parsing strings like this makes me immediately want a drink. Not jealous of you right now...